# Saving output from "If statement" c#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, out

I have a conditional as such:

```
List<HWSRunSession> session = new List<HWSRunSession>();
foreach (var item in fileInfo)
{
    if(_db.HWSRunSessions.Where((x) => x.TransferredZipName == item.Name 
    && DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.AddedDate).TotalDays >= _ExpirationDays) == null) {
     bla bla...
    }        
}
```

But I want to save the list I retrieve in the conditional to my variable `session` using the "out" key word. kind of like:

```
List<HWSRunSession> session = new List<HWSRunSession>();
foreach (var item in fileInfo)
{
    if(_db.HWSRunSessions.Where((x) => x.TransferredZipName == item.Name 
    && DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.AddedDate).TotalDays >= _ExpirationDays), out session == null) {



    }
}
```

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: `if` has no support for an `out` parameter, or rather anything else besides a single condition. Is there any particular reason why you want this?

Comment: Don't make it too complicated. 1. Get the list, 2. Apply condition.

Comment: you can simply assign to a variable and check it for `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most readable and maintainable solution is to store the result in a variable, *then* test this variable in the condition:

```
var session = _db.HWSRunSessions
    .Where((x) => x.TransferredZipName == item.Name 
       && DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.AddedDate).TotalDays >= _ExpirationDays)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if(session == null)
{
  // session is null
}
else
{
  // do something with session
}
```

If you *absolutely must* assign a variable within an expression, it is possible. But it makes the code more difficult to read and easier to miss bugs:

```
Session session = null;
if ((session = _db.HWSRunSessions
    .Where((x) => x.TransferredZipName == item.Name 
        && DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.AddedDate).TotalDays >= _ExpirationDays)
    .FirstOrDefault()) == null)
{
  // session is null
}
else
{
  // do something with session
}
```

Comment: I have written the same thing in comment

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this should actually _never_ be null. Assuming `HWSRunSessions` is a `DBSet<T>`, `Where` should _always_ return an `IQueryable`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Fildor yes, you are absolutely correct. `Where` will always (99% ;)) return non-null. Probably another `.FirstOrDefault()` call is missing from the OP

Comment: The solution is ok, but anyway that conditional code is weird, I would write a method that returns the session value and keep it clean

Comment: @Windgate agree, a method makes the condition more readable. The question was about storing the value of an expression in a variable from within the if condition. The expression could be anything (a single method call, LINQ, a complex arithmetic expression, etc.)